# A relative clause with multiple prepositions

Tags: relative-clauses

Is it correct to say:

> Microbial biology is a field in which I am interested and for which I have passion."

What about:

> Microbial biology is a field which I am interested in and I have passion for."

Comment: A sentence can be correct and also need help to do its job better. If the job of this sentence is to excite the reader about your great interest in Micro, it's sleeping on the job. Blame the structure you chose, similar to the standard example of a bad passive voice: *A good time was had by all*. Does that sound like a fun party? **I am passionate about Microbial biology.**

Comment: Both are syntactically fine. *Idiomatically* the second version is more likely. Except most native speakers would "delete" the second instance of subject pronoun ***I***, AND would probably add the indefinite article *(**a**)* before ***passion***.

Comment: 'Microbial biology is a field which I am interested in ... in fact, have a passion for." The (essentially twin) relative clauses are hyponymic/augmentive rather than cumulative.

Comment: If you have a passion, you already have an interest, so no need to say it twice: _Microbial biology is a field **that**I have **a** passion for._ Better yet: _I have a passion for microbial biology._